# Xcode UITesting when working with my server

Tags: ios, xcode, api-design, uitest

This is my first application for uitesting. Please guide me for the correct set up. I have login screen. After login I need to get some details from user. So I have 5 vc's. Each view I'm collecting some data and submit button. Now on each submit I'm calling API and saving data to my server.

1. How to write uitest cases.
2. Do I need to call apis again inside my test target.

   3. I want to start with login and logout uitesting
   4. How to maintain logout cases while writing tests .

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Xcode supports UI tests. All needed knowledge is in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html).

**2.** Your view controllers will call the API during the tests - as if a real user would use the app and trigger the calls

**3.** and **4.** I recommend trying to implement it. It should be pretty straightforward. You could check out this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/150073/ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial).

Comment: Let's say I have login API. I will pass email and password to the api based on API response I will check login success or failed. Now I how to know whether user successfully logged in in my test case.

Comment: You would simply check whether ui that should appear after the login screen appeared. Alternatively you could also check if the login ui disappeared

Comment: My UI depends on API response. As I said  in my question, once user logged in I need to show him 5 view controller one by one and finally dashboard. Now I want to testonboarding. Which should execute all the 5 vc's code and I need to know whether every thing is working fine or not.

Comment: Have you actually tried to do it? I explained pretty much everything and dunno what to add. It’s pretty straightforward when you read the docs and skim a tutorial

Comment: Sorry for not getting it correctly. I will go through the tutorial and will get back to you.